# How to send OTP in Codeigniter by using textlocal sms api?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, sms

I have written code to send OTP in codeigniter by using textlocalapi and loading class file(textlocal.class.php) in controller using require function but whenever I enter my mobile number it is not sending any otp to that number.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require ('./textlocal.class.php');

class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User_Model');
        $this->load->helper('string');

    }  ?>
```

this my folder structure for textlocal.class.php file
 [image]

Below code written in model for sending otp

```
public function send_otp(){
        $data['otp'] = random_string('numeric',6);
        $data['otp_id'] = random_string('alnum',6);
        $this->db->insert('otp',$data);

        // Account details
    $apiKey = urlencode('xyz');// My API key

    // Message details
    $numbers = 911234567894;
    $sender = urlencode('ABCDEF');//This my six digit sender name
    $message = rawurlencode('This is your message');



    // Prepare data for POST request
    $data = array('apikey' => $apiKey, 'numbers' => $numbers, "sender" => $sender, "message" => $message);

    // Send the POST request with cURL
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.textlocal.in/send/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Process your response here
    return $response;


    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? You can confirm by printing this `$response;` If there is no error, then check if your number is not registered with `DND (Do Not Disturb)` list with the operator. You can check the status of DND for the number you're trying online.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay in controller I am using print_r($response) but it is getting empty and also mobile number is not In DND, OTP details inserting in table properly but otp is not getting to that number.

Comment: Then the problem is with your API. since your curl response was empty.

Comment: StoringOTP to DB is a different matter. There are several things to confirm, check that you have sufficient balance (credit) with TextLocal account. Also check the log on Textlocal account. You will see all the requests you have made if they reached to the API ever. If there is not log, then you have some issue with your code only.